# Do we apply a different standard to social science questions than to hard science?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I asked this question, and it was closed as "unclear":

[Is there scientific evidence to support a distinction between "Ask" and "Guess" cultures?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/35257/is-there-scientific-evidence-to-support-a-distinction-between-ask-and-guess)

Ordinarily, I would chalk this up to the general unreasonableness of people who disagree with me and move on, but someone made this comment on the question:

> I'm not sure there's a clear claim to scientifically examine here (as opposed to a fairly wide field). It's a very interesting topic, but **I have a feeling the question would be a better fit on a social science or psychology site.**

(Bold added)

After reading that, *I* have a feeling that a physics question with a similar level of detail would not have been closed.  But maybe I'm unable to look at this objectively.

Do we want to hold social science to a higher standard?  And regardless, was this a good closure or a bad closure?

Comment: A similarly vague-about-claim question (see Sklivvz's answer below, he expressed it far better than I could) would also be a better fit on Physics (if on-topic there) than here. (I'm the person who posted the quoted comment, BTW, which is why I decided to comment)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think we do. Your question does not really have a clear claim you are skeptical about, it's basically asking for evidence on a whole topic.

While it is a *valid* and *interesting* question, it would not work as-is on this site, but it would probably work on a specific science site. We routinely close and migrate questions to specific sites when they are good questions, but bad fits.

I think in this case we can turn this into a valid question. It's just unclear what is the claim you are skeptical of:

- that there are these two ways of communicating? I think this is pretty obvious.
- that these two ways are actually the only two "cultures"?
- that people use only one or the other (so it's actually a characterization, not merely a chosen behavior)?
- that there are no nuances between the two?

None of this is clear to me from either your quote or your question. Think about what exactly is the claim that bothers you, find an example of it, and post it. Your question will be fine.

Comment: "I think this is pretty obvious." - That's the trouble with social science. Everyone thinks everything is obvious, so no one is skeptical of anything.  Would you apply that attitude to physics?

Comment: @Kevin The trouble is that this is *not claimed to be social science*. AFAICT it's a random observation of a Metafilter OP, and yes I would say the same to a question about a physical phenomenon which I witness commonly. The *phenomenon* exists. Whether it's a *scientific* fact is something different, but that no one seems to claim in your question :-)

Comment: @Kevin let's me ask you: what would a good answer look like?